# Grep AWS S3 command output

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, grep

When running: `aws s3 cp` command to upload a file from local to S3 it shows the following output:

```
upload: ./test.txt to s3://demo-bucket/test.txt
```

How do I extract only `s3://demo-bucket/test.txt` string from the command output using `grep`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pipe the command to [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) as follows:

```
grep -o 's3:\/\/.*$'
#s3://demo-bucket/test.txt
```

Note the usage of the `-o` flag, which tells [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) to only return the matched string.

---

You may also consider piping to [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '{print $4}'
#s3://demo-bucket/test.txt
```

which will print the fourth field of the string.